# Getting Drawable Resource

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, drawable, android-resources

I am using MonoDevelop for Android and i am trying to create a Drawable variable from an image in the resources folder.

I have the following files in my Resources\drawable folder:

```
Icon.png
monkey.png
monkeyPurple.png
```

How do I create a Drawable variable that has the image obtained from one of these files?

I have tried the following code:

```
Drawable icon = Drawable.CreateFromPath("Icon.png");
```

This however does not work. If this is the correct way to load an image from file, do I need to have the full filename and path to the file? I have tried many combinations to access the image, with no luck.

I have also tried the following:

```
Drawable icon = R.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.Icon); 
Drawable icon = R.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.monkey);
```

Also with no luck.

Can I please have some help in correctly creating a Drawable variable that has an image from the resource folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're very close, but I think you're mixing Java and C#.

You can access this using the `Resource` structure. I've put both the Mono for Android and Java versions below for reference but in your case you want the C# version if you're using Mono for Android.

**Mono for Android (C#)**

```
Drawable icon = Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.Icon);
```

**Android SDK (Java)**

```
Resources res = getResources();
Drawable icon = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.Icon);
```

Answer (score 4):

As of Android **API** version **21**, the old method is deprecated and replaced by the following:

```
Drawable icon = ResourcesCompat.GetDrawable(Resources, Resource.Drawable.Icon, null);
```

For more details check the original [Android answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041027/android-getresources-getdrawable-deprecated-api-22#answer-29146895)

Comment: What is Resources in this scenario?